# Saving a file to a specific location

Tags: java, file, location

I am trying to save a file to the C Drive using

`File file = new File ("C:/file.txt")`

The file does appear there, however information doesn't get saved onto it and it remains blank. Why?

When I save the file to the location of the source code it works fine it just won't save when I try to write it to the C drive.

Comment: Because you have a bug in your code.

Comment: @JbNizet is it supposed to be a joke?

Comment: No, it's supposed to make the OP realize that we can't tell him where and why his code is wrong if he doesn't show his code.

Comment: Make sure you are closing your output stream.  Although in the code you provided you aren't writing to the file anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

**Close the file after writing....... or reading...... ITS IMPORTANT..TRY THIS ..**

Use `close()` method...

Answer (score 0):

Try following this example

```
import java.io.*;
 public class InputStreamToFile {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   try {
        File f=new File("outFile.java");
        InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream("InputStreamToFile.java");
        OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
               int len;
               while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
               out.write(buf,0,len);
               out.close();
               inputStream.close();
   System.out.println("\nFile is created..........");
   }
   catch (IOException e){}
   }  
 }
```

[enter link description here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/InputstreamToFile.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

use close() after you finished job,also be sure ,you have permission to that Folder to write